# How to export data from HDFS to neo4j

Tags: hadoop, neo4j, hdfs

I have my input file in HDFS. How to store that data to Neo4j db.
Is there any way to do the same?
Already found links regarding neo4j using hive as data source.

But not able to find input source as HDFS.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Did you find any way for this? I am trying to load csv from hdfs to neo4j thanks